# Failed to connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am not connecting MySQL server. I didn't change password. I got following errors.

Connect server error:

[image: MySQL Workbench]

Test connection error:

[image: Manage Server Connection]

How to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: The error message says it all: the user root connecting from host localhost with a password is not allowed to do so. Hence or more of the 3 factors are wrong (is there is a user named root?, is the password correct that you used?, is root allowed to connect from localhost?). If you can answer all 3 questions with 100% certainty then you will be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried connecting from a terminal ?

> mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306

Comment: I tried connecting from terminal. When I entered password, getting following error.
_mysql: Unknown OS character set 'cp857'.
mysql: Switching to the default character set 'latin1'.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)_

Comment: ok ...  In this case just grant the permission :  mysql >GRANT ALL ON [DatabaseName].* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';    let me know please

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reconfigure the password using the installer you downloaded to install Mysql in your machine.

Steps:

1. Double click your installer
2. select reconfigure link next to MYsql server
3. click next till you were asked to set up password. Then Enter your password
4. Click execute. and you are done. ou can try to connect again.

Check this video for reference.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8L1GKGLmyUk